# If total variation function for f of bounded variation is absolutely continuous, then f is absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

Suppose that $f$ is a function of bounded variation on [0, 1], and let $V(x)$ be the total variation function for $f$, i.e., for any $x \in [0, 1]$, $V(x)$ is the total variation of $f$ on the interval $[0, x]$. Prove that, if $V$ is absolutely continuous on [0, 1], then so is $f$.

My attempt:

First, I note that $\sum_{k = 1}^{n} |V(b_{k}) - V(a_{k})| = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} |TV(f_{[a_{k}, b_{k}]})|$. Then I note that $|f(b_{k}) - f(a_{k})|$ would be the variation for the crudest possible partition of $(a_{k}, b_{k})$, hence $|f(b_{k}) - f(a_{k})| \leq TV(f_{[a_{k}, b_{k}]})$ for each $k$. Thus if we choose the $\delta$ responding to the $\epsilon$ challenge for the absolute continuity of function $V$, we have that if $\sum_{k = 1}^{n} [b_{k} - a_{k}] < \delta$ for a collection of open intervals $\{(a_{k}, b_{k})\}_{k = 1}^{n}$ in [0, 1], then:

$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} |f(b_{k}) - f(a_{k})| \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{n} TV(f_{[a_{k}, b_{k}]}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} |V(b_{k}) - V(a_{k})| < \epsilon$

Comment: What does $TV(f,P_k)$ mean, exactly? The notation looks like it means something like the total variation of $f$ with respect to $P_k$, but that makes little sense.

Comment: Sorry, it's sloppy. I was trying to indicate the total variation of f taken over all possible partitions $P_{k}$ of the interval $(a_{k}, b_{k})$. Fixed.

Comment: Makes more sense now. Of course people are still wondering what your question is.

Comment: Just checking my work---with real analysis I'm still building self-confidence, because I tend to make blunders.

Comment: Fine. You can get in big trouble for not following the Rules. One of the rules is that when you post a "question" you're supposed to ask a _question_. "Is the following proof correct?" is in fact an acceptable question...

Comment: Oh okay, sorry about that. Sometimes I see people use "my attempt:..." or "just checking my work" as a synonym for that. Glad it looks good.